# How could I correctly say "I moved here when I was eight years old"?

Tags: sentence-structure, simplified-characters, introductions

I am working on a self-introduction, and say where I was born. How could I correctly say that I moved house when I was 8 years old?

Comment: Feed the sentence to Google Translate, you get -- 我八岁时搬到这里来.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In everyday Chinese:我八岁时搬来这儿；

In scholar Chinese: 本人八岁移居此地；

In snobbish Chinese: 在下八岁乔迁至此；

In pre-Qin Dynasty Chinese：吾自八龄谪居本地。

For your reference only.